# IODocs - Passing cookie between API calls

Tags: cookies, flask, iodocs

I have a REST website built with flask, and use its session cookie features to keep a very basic 'login' (I don't require security).

I'm trying to implement iodocs documentation. The "/login" works fine, and I also see the response with the cookie being sent, but I can't figure out how to tell iodocs to keep that cookie for the next API calls.

Any help (that wouldn't require my site to change to OAuth) would be very appritiated.